# Hide 'add to cart' when certain value in dropdown is selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, function, dropdown

*In relation to question asked on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377962/hide-add-to-cart-when-certain-value-in-dropdown-is-selected)*

I am trying to hide the 'add to cart' woocommerce button when a user selects a specific item in a dropdown list. I am using the WordPress platform and have tried multiple JQuery snippets in both functions.php and through 3rd party plugins but am still struggling to get it to work.

**In Functions.php theme file**

```
function load_scripts() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document.getElementsByName("select-1574795073993")).change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="International"){
                    $(".single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Please can someone assist with simple steps to 1) provide correct code, and 2) insert in the woocommerce.com hosted plarform.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code.

```
function load_scripts(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select[name="select-1574795073993"]').on('change', function() {
                    if( this.value == "International" && $('.product_meta .by-vendor-name-link').text() == 'Sold By Ronks Michael' ){
                        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
                    }else{
                        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").show(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Bhautik - I have enclosed the code in functions.php
function load_scripts() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
....................your script above............
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
But its still not working, can you assist. Thanks

Comment: @Bhuatik - You sir are a legend... it worked! :) Thank you very much

Comment: In addition to the above, I would like to add an AND clause so that also if the item is sold by Ronks Michael that it will hide button as well

E.g. of the source code:

    <a class="by-vendor-name-link" style="display: block;" href="https://picflick.co.za/vendor/ronks-michael/">Sold By Ronks Michael</a>

So when it = Sold By Ronks Michael the if statement will be true.

Thank you

Comment: (or anyone) - Can you please assist mate

Comment: Thanks very much for attending to. Interesting situation here... there is more than 1 <a class="by-vendor-name-link" > tag. The 1 I am looking for is contained in a <div class="product_meta"> tag. Are you able to add that? I tried $(".product_meta.by-vendor-name-link").text() == "Sold By Ronks Michael" ) but that did not work. Please help :)

Comment: @Greg can you share the link where this "product meta" is so I can understand better.

Comment: Sure the link is https://picflick.co.za/product/3-different-paths/ Just do a CTRL+F to find it

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much @Bhautik . I did that, but did not separate the class names. Thanks for teaching me :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I would like to add an AND clause so that also if the item is sold by Ronks Michael that it will hide button as well

E.g. of the source code:

```
<a class="by-vendor-name-link" style="display: block;" href="https://picflick.co.za/vendor/ronks-michael/">Sold By Ronks Michael</a>
```

So when it = "Sold By Ronks Michael" the if statement will be true.

Thank you